# Fastest access to vertex attribute

Tags: r, igraph

Given a small graph such as:

```
mygraph <-barabasi.game(5)
V(mygraph)$color <- 1:vcount(mygraph)
V(mygraph)$name <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
```

If I compare these methods to get a vertex attribute:

```
benchmark(V(mygraph)$color[5],
          V(mygraph)[5]$color,
          vertex_attr(mygraph, 'color', V(mygraph)[5]),
          vertex_attr(mygraph, 'color', 5),
          vertex_attr(mygraph, 'color', 'five'),
          replications=1000)
```

It turns out that `vertex_attr`, either with vertex id or name, gives the fastest results:

```
                                          test replications elapsed relative
4             vertex_attr(mygraph, "color", 5)         1000   0.016    1.000
5        vertex_attr(mygraph, "color", "five")         1000   0.287   17.937
3 vertex_attr(mygraph, "color", V(mygraph)[5])         1000   1.113   69.562
2                          V(mygraph)[5]$color         1000  33.111 2069.437
1                          V(mygraph)$color[5]         1000  24.403 1525.187
```

Given that I need the fastest method because I'm using this in a loop, should I use this way of accessing the attributes? (I hesitate because this is not explicitly said in the docs)

Comment: Yes, if this works for you, feel free to use it. `V` does a lot of magic (too much), so it is much slower.